# why does it appear can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' ? I think I already give the width and height an integer velue. Thanks

Tags: python

```
# This is a calcualtor

shape = raw_input('what shape do you want to calculate? rectangle, circle, triangle, square? ')

if shape == 'rectangle':

    width = raw_input('Please tell me the width of rectangle: ')
    height = raw_input('Please tell me the height of rectangle: ')
    print 'the area of the rectange is: ', width*height

elif shape == 'circle':
    radius = raw_input('Please tell me the radius of the circle: ')
    print 'the area of the circle is: ', 3.14 * int(radius)**2
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample inputs, erroneous outputs and the desired output rather than just code, also it looks like you're not casting `width` and `height` to `int` which is why you get your error: `width = int(raw_input('Please tell me the width of rectangle: '))`

Comment: In `rectangle` you don't convert `width` and `height` to integer. Also in both `if` your print statement is wrong, it's like you're multiplying the string with the number. Try `print 'the area of the circle is: %d' % (3.14 * int(radius)**2)` Also checkout https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` returns a string. Use `width = int(raw_input(...))`, and the same thing for `height` to convert them to actual integers. Demo:

```
>>> width = raw_input('Please tell me the width of rectangle: ')
Please tell me the width of rectangle:  5
>>> width
'5'
>>> type(width)
<type 'str'>
>>> width * width
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>> width_int = int(width)
>>> width_int
5
>>> type(width_int)
<type 'int'>
>>> width_int * width_int
25
```

Use `float` instead of `int` if you want numbers that have a fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

You get `can't multiply sequence of non-int of type 'str'` because `width` & `height` are str.

In **python 2.x** use:

```
width = int(raw_input('Please tell me the width of rectangle: '))
```

In **python 3.x** use:

```
width = int(input('Please tell me the width of rectangle: '))
```

By default `input` or `raw_input` return a string.

You may **use `float()` instead of `int()` for decimal/floating point numbers**.

**Alternatively**, you may take both the inputs on a single line :

```
side = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Your input in the above case maybe :

And you get a list `side` which contains the `width` & `height` as integers.